# WPF/WinForm not receiving touch events

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, touch

I'm trying to create a fullscreen WPF application and trying to implement a android like navigation drawer.
[image]

So in order to accomplish this I have to detect a swipe coming from offscreen, just like the Windows 8 charm bar.
[image]

But windows does not sent any touch/mouse events to the application if the swipe didn't start on the touchscreen (global hook isn't working too).

How am I able to detect those swipes starting offscreen just like Windows does it for the charm bar?

Just if it matters I'm using a Surface pro 3 with Win 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add manipulation events on your screen/window to detect if any swipe event takes place on your screen. There is no way that you directly get that event offscreen. 
Referring to this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansont/archive/2010/01/11/multi-touch-in-wpf-4-part-3-manipulation-events.aspx) may help you.

Comment: I set IsManipulationEnabled to true for my window but I still don't receive any events like ManipulationStarted if the swipe started offscreen. Windows seems to register the touch events because it draws a trail at my finger but it doesn't send those messages into the message loop.

Comment: @Dobbias Register ManipulationStarted event and place a break point on the event. see whether you are able to hit the breakpoint when you swipe on your screen.

Comment: I am able to hit it if the swipe started on the screen, but if I enter the screen from the border the event is not being triggered.

Comment: yes because when you try to swipe from corner say border it is a child control on your other control, the manipulation events does not trigger for border.

Comment: My window is completely empty there are no child controls on it. Even a global mouse hook can't detect those swipes coming from offscreen and entering the screen. But Windows somehow is able to for the charm bar. I oberserved this behaviour for other stock applications too e.g. the windows explorer doesn't highlight files if the swipe starts offscreen and then hovers the window. But Windows draws a semi transparent so the os is actually getting the events but it's not sending them to non metro apps/windows. I need a way to solve this problem.